# Error COR_E_NEWER_RUNTIME when creating COM class from side by side assembly

Tags: delphi, c#-4.0, dll, sharpdevelop, side-by-side

I have the following situation:

- A native Delphi application should call a COM interface from a C# DLL
- I want do cooperate the application and DLL without registering the C# DLL (side by side)

**Delphi application code (console executable):**

```
program TestSideBySide2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  mscorlib_TLB in 'mscorlib_TLB.pas',
  TestSideBySide2_TLB in 'TestSideBySide2_TLB.pas';

var
   sideBySide : TestSideBySide2_TLB._SideBySideClass;
   intfSideBySide : TestSideBySide2_TLB.ISideBySideClass;
   res : HRESULT;

begin
  try
      sideBySide := TestSideBySide2_TLB.CoSideBySideClass.Create();
      res := sideBySide.QueryInterface(IID_ISideBySideClass,intfSideBySide);

      Writeln(intfSideBySide.Version());

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

The imported `'TestSideBySide2_TLB.pas'` was generated from the DLL using the `TLIBIMP.exe` tool.

Here's the application manifest that would be linked to the Delphi application as resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"
          xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <assemblyIdentity 
    type="win32"
    name="TestSideBySide.exe"
    version = "1.0.0.0" />
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="TestSideBySide2"
        version="1.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

**C# DLL code (compiled using SharpDevelop)**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: Guid("07F9C367-BFA4-45AD-8A60-689096BD7AA9")]

namespace TestSideBySide2
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Exposed interface.
    /// </summary>
    [Guid("49D49031-12D8-40B5-85FA-B42133FD7DD0")]
    public interface ISideBySideClass
    {
        string Version();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation of exposed interface.
    /// </summary>
    [Guid("A0BDB20B-A6E4-4A36-A64C-CC9186DD1C3E")]
    public class SideBySideClass : ISideBySideClass
    {
        public string Version()
        {
            return "1.0.0-C#";
        }
    }
}
```

And the assembly manifest (also linked as a resource into the DLL):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
  manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity
                type="win32"
                name="TestSideBySide2"
                version="1.0.0.0" />
    <clrClass
                clsid="{A0BDB20B-A6E4-4A36-A64C-CC9186DD1C3E}"
                progid="TestSideBySide2"
                threadingModel="Both"
                name="TestSideBySide2.SideBySideClass" >
    </clrClass>
</assembly>
```

---

Everything fairly simple so far. The Delphi application can resolve the bindings and the DLL will be loaded. But the line

```
sideBySide := TestSideBySide2_TLB.CoSideBySideClass.Create();
```

fails with the exception

```
EOleSysError: OLE-Error 8013101B, ClassID: {A0BDB20B-A6E4-4A36-A64C-CC9186DD1C3E}
```

The error code resolves to `COR_E_NEWER_RUNTIME`.

---

I checked the .NET runtime version the DLL was build for, and that's .NET 4.0 (which is available on my Windows 10 environment).

Then I tried to build the DLL for older runtime versions (2.0, 3.0, 3.5), and for each of them it worked just fine.

---

Of course I've been researching what could be the problem, and here's what I found so far promising to remedy the problem (but didn't):

- [Cannot get to work VB.NET DLL referenced by VB6 client in reg-free scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469592/cannot-get-to-work-vb-net-dll-referenced-by-vb6-client-in-reg-free-scenario)
- [How to: Configure .NET Framework-Based COM Components for Registration-Free Activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/eew13bza(v=vs.110).aspx) (using the `runtimeVersion="v1.4"` attribute in the DLL manifest `clrClass` element specifically)

Currently I'm out of ideas what else could be done. Any further resources I found on the internet merely point to one of the proposals I've listed above.

What else could I've been overlooking there?

---

Update:

A colleague mentioned it could be a Delphi oddness and calling from unmanaged code.

We're using Embarcadero Seattle Delphi 10.

Comment: This [brief MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/tag/cor_e_newer_runtime/) talks about the `COR_E_NEWER_RUNTIME` error.

Comment: @Ron The (less brief) and interesting information lurks here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/05/17/registration-free-com-net-interop.aspx THX! ;-)

Comment: @Ron Thanks again. The link you gave me finally led me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem with help of the information found here:

[**Runtime Versions and Errors 0x80131700 and 0x8013101b**](http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/howto.htm)

I had already done an attempt to add the .NET CLR version at the assembly manifest of the DLL. This can be done per class in the `clrClass` section.
What I didn't knew was, that the `runtimeVersion` attribute must be fully qualified.

The full `clrClass` section looks like this now:

```
<clrClass
            clsid="{A0BDB20B-A6E4-4A36-A64C-CC9186DD1C3E}"
            progid="TestSideBySide2"
            threadingModel="Both"
            name="TestSideBySide2.SideBySideClass" 
            runtimeVersion="v4.0.30319">
</clrClass>
```

According to the document linked above the version entries for other CLR versions should be:

> - v1.0.3705
> - v1.1.4322
> - v2.0.50727
> - v4.0.30319